# How do I reset/change my security questions on my Apple Id

Tags: security, apple-id

I have an Apple ID and I know my password, but forgot the answer to the security question. I tried to change it at appleid.apple.com but we don't have a link to reset it. See the picture. Please help me ASAP.[image: Screenshot of Edit your Apple ID website]

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the link as you only get a few attempts at getting the answers correct.

[Apple Support Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6170)

> If you can't reset your security questions
>
> Contact Apple Support in either of these circumstances:
>
> > You don't see the link to send a reset email, which means you don't have a rescue address.
> >
> > You see the link to send a reset email, but you don't have access to email at the rescue address.
>
> A temporary support PIN isn't usually required, but Apple may ask you to generate a PIN if your identity needs to be verified.